# A proof for a continuous differentiable function

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that for a continuous differentiable function, if there is not any minimum between two minima of the function then there is a maximum between them and this maximum is unique.

Comment: I want to prove that in a continuous function mins and maxes are sequentially

Comment: It means that after a min there should be a maximum  or min,max,min,max.....

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b$ the points where those minima are attained.

If $f(a)>f(b)$, then there is some point $x\in(a,b)$ where $f(x)>f(a)$, otherwise $a$ wouldn't be a local minimum. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem there is $b'\in(x,b)$ such that $f(a)=f(b')$.

Similarly if $f(a)<f(b)$ there is $a'\in(a,b)$ such that $f(a')=f(b)$.

Therefore, we can assume that $f(a)=f(b)$. Since $f$ can't be constant, there are points where the function is strictly larger than $f(a)$. Since $f$ is continuous is has a maximum in $[a,b]$, but since there are points in which the value is larger than $f(a)=f(b)$, the maximum must be in $(a,b)$.

If there were two maxima, then a similar argument as above, would show that in between them there are minima.

Comment: Beat me to it. In particular, this argument doesn't need to assume differentiability, much less continuous differentiability.

Comment: thanks  for your help

Comment: Yes.its true. I did not try to prove in such a manner.I was using the derivative properties so I was forced to consider some constraints.